# Add row headers to an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

In me wanting to not add a long boring description, I might have done the opposite, so I'm adding more details to this question:

What I'm trying to do is gather some inputs that are currently spread across 4 sheets, with no clear structure, in a large and slow Excel file, into 1 table so we can streamline the file, make it faster and possibly compatible with a Database in the future.

Right now the inputs are identified by named ranges, and most of them have formulas containing references to other inputs defined by named ranges.
I was hoping that if I just move the named range references to the Excel automated table that would be ok, but I found it that sorting the table causes the named ranges to lose their references (they don't sort with the table), so I'm looking for a way to identify rows in the table without actually using lookup formulas (something similar to how you identify columns by their name), if that is even possible. There are 2 reasons I would not use lookup formulas: lookup formulas would slow down the file and some formulas would end up looking at the same column where the formula is, ending in a circular reference.

Is there a way I can add row headers or index to an Excel table (large one), so that I can use a chess like Row+Column name reference, and it would still be valid even if you sort the table?

What I tried:

- having a row containing keys, and using Index/Match or vlookup => the table is to large, and using a lookup functionality like this would slow it down. Also the values are on the same column, so I would get circular reference.
- i tried with named ranges => if you sort a Table, the named ranges stay in place, they are independent of the table, and the references would no longer be valid.

Comment: Welcome!  Would love to help but the description is too difficult to follow without a point of reference.  Spreadsheets are inherently referenced by coordinates.  What does it mean for a reference to be valid after sorting the table?    Why not attach a simple spreadsheet sheet with some sample data (a small sample table) to better illustrate what you mean.

Comment: Please post some sample data with your attempted solution. Currently it's not clear how exactly your solution want working. (Circular reference? No longer valid named range?)

Comment: How big is the table and what is the end goal? It seems unlikely that it would be so big as to not be possible to either use INDEX/MATCH, XLOOKUP, PQ or FILTER to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something unexpected buried in the paucity of information you gave, then `NO`, there is no way to do this without using lookup features unless you use VBA.

The only way what you did write makes any sense at all is that you would add a row of column headers, letter based, and a column row headers, number based, to your table. Since presumably you don't sort by columns, any more than anyone else in the world does, the important ones would be the row headers. If you sort by rows, you'd include that column so the same number that started the row would always start the row. Note that it must be so as, if you desired they always stay in place, they'd be no different than row numbers, remaining in place and so disconnecting from their pre-sort data, so why have them at all as row numbers are always there?

Yet, once you sort with them included, they are all jumbled. So how is Excel to know where they are without a lookup of some kind? Even VBA would be using a lookup of some sort, with its advantage chiefly being the speed VBA can do things with, though that is not always the winner versus functions.

As to lookups of some kind, I paired it down to an Index and a Match. With 27 columns (I didn't care to address what to do for more than the alphabet with so very little to go on), and 240,000 rows, the result was instantaneous and it included 18 functions and another 5-10 operations. 6,480,000 cells to examine, if badly written, and it was instantaneous. And that was the end result of trying to avoid anything closer to a lookup than using `INDEX` to create the address to find a value in. Given lookups must be used in SOME way, I'm sure it could be terser and therefore faster (than instantaneous... hmm... not much practical goal there).

So, your bar to rise above is either:

1. No, the table just is not too big for using lookups in some way. (True regardless.) So after the framework of headers is added, you use standard string manipulation to break apart your chess notation for two useful pieces of information and then lookups using that.

Or,

2. Give some meaningful detail so a person can see some way that a table really is too big for using any kind of lookups.

Last note:  the reason it was instantaneous is that it was not searching mangy real world data cell by cell for a match. It was being given information letting it use `MATCH` on a column of straightforward and numeric data, and a separate one on the 26 lettered column headers. So lickety-split, into an `INDEX` that gave Excel a single cell address to read. Lookups do not have to be used to examine all 6,500,000 cells and so do not have to be slow. In addition, the cells looked through contain "array constants" or as humans know them, simple numbers and letters, so there are no found formulas to maybe have to calculate. Excel can quickly (essentially instantaneously) see there is no calculation needed before evaluating the elements to return the result. Even if the result is a cell with a nasty formula hiding amongst 6,359,972 other cells all with formulas. It does no calculation, just the check, before the lookup and returns the current value so not even a calculation run after finding the cell it needs.

Comment: There may be more gracious or professional ways to communicate this, also shorter ones too, especially when you're essentially asking OP to add some information to their question.